# Using namespaces in non-class files

Tags: php, namespaces

I am creating a function file in PHP, for this I want to use a namespace.

Does the namespace encompass all of the file or does it only cover certain parts?

An example would be:

```
namespace Functions;

function foo()
{
    return "foo";
}

function bar()
{
    return "bar";
}
```

Or would it be:

```
namespace Functions;

function foo()
{
    return "foo";
}

namespace Functions;

function bar()
{
    return "bar";
}
```

*Shown as one file for both the examples*

Comment: yes, you use auto-loading for classes, The spl_autoload_register() function registers any number of autloaders, enabling for classes and interfaces to be automatically loaded if they are currently not defined. By registering autoloaders, PHP is given a last chance to load the class or interface before it fails with an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create static classes for that:

```
namespace helpers;
class Hello
{
    private static $greeting = 'Hello';
    private static $initialized = false;

    private static function initialize()
    {
        if (self::$initialized)
            return;

        self::$greeting .= ' There!';
        self::$initialized = true;
    }

    public static function greet()
    {
        self::initialize();
        echo self::$greeting;
    }
}
```

Without you are not using OOP which namespaces are a part of

Comment: So to use a namespace it has to be OOP is the general idea of this?

Comment: That is how namespaces are used, you can include other .php files with `use`  and call it's functions. But OOP is really nice to use